# Updating nested state array react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

[image]I have done a lot of research and I saw a lot of similar questions but non answer this.
I am trying to update a nested array, I have tried a lot of different variations but non work.

```
onChange={(e) => setUser([{ ...User[index], permissions : {CreateSubs : e.target.value} }])}
```

Right now this of course erases the other items I have inside of permissions arr, how do I just update the specific one I need?

```
     [
      {
        User: {
          name: "Name",
          permissions: {
            CreateSubs: true,
            CreateOtherStuff: false,
          },
        },
      },
    ]
```

**Update**

All the other article i found are not using react hooks, and it's a bit different

Below is what worked for me

```
onChange={(e) => setUser([ { ...User[index], permissions: { ...User[index].permissions, CreateSubs: e.target.checked } } ])}
```

Comment: try using Array.map function, with condition like ```array.map(function (a) { if(a.user.name === '') { return  { ...a, user: {...a.user, permission:{ ...a.user.permission, <new value>}}}}})```

Comment: I'm assuming you're using `useState` for this? i.e.,
`const [user, setUser] = useState({});
...
<Component onChange={(e) => setUser(...)} />
`
Your data model isn't totally clear here. You said you have a  permissions array, but permissions is an object. And User has a capital U in the first snippet but a lower case u in the second one

Comment: @MikeYoung that was a mistake, i wrote it manually in the post, ill update it. and yes im using const [user, setUser] = useState({});

Comment: I finally figured it out  `onChange={(e) => setUser([ { ...User[index], permissions: { ...User[index].permissions, CreateSubs: e.target.checked } } ])}  `